# Oauth access token Request is missing required authentication credential while inserting event into google calendar android

Tags: google-oauth, google-calendar-api

When I am inserting the events into the Google calendar of my google account but it was throwing the 401 unauthorized error.

I am using the following code to add events to the calendar.

```
Event _calendarEvent = new Event()
                                .setSummary(_calendarData.get(0).get_calenderTitle())
                                .setDescription("AppName");
                        CommonUtility.convertDateFormat(_calendarData.get(0)
                                        .get_startTime(), "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm",
                                "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:m:ssZZZZZ");


                        DateTime startDateTime = new DateTime(CommonUtility.convertDateFormat(_calendarData.get(0).get_startTime(), "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZZ"));
                        
                        EventDateTime start = new EventDateTime()
                                .setDateTime(startDateTime)
                                .setTimeZone(tz.getID());
                        start.setDateTime(startDateTime);
                        _calendarEvent.setStart(start);


                        DateTime endDateTime = new DateTime(CommonUtility.convertDateFormat(_calendarData.get(0).get_endTime(), "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZZ"));
                        EventDateTime end = new EventDateTime()
                                .setDateTime(endDateTime)
                                .setTimeZone(tz.getID());
                        end.setDateTime(endDateTime);
                        _calendarEvent.setEnd(end);
//401 unauthorized exception thrown by the insert method below.
Event _eventLogged = mService.events().insert(_credential.getSelectedAccountName(), _calendarEvent).execute();
```

The I am facing is shown below.

```
{
  "code": 401,
  "message": "Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.",
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Login Required.",
      "domain": "global",
      "reason": "required",
      "location": "Authorization",
      "locationType": "header"
    }
  ],
  "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED"
}
```

Authorization code

```
HttpTransport transport = AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport();
            JsonFactory jsonFactory = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
            mService = new Calendar.Builder(
                    transport, jsonFactory, credential)
                    .setApplicationName("AppName")
                    .build();
```

GoogleCredential code

```
mCredential = GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(
            getApplicationContext(), Arrays.asList(SCOPES))
            .setBackOff(new ExponentialBackOff());
```

Comment: Please edit your question and include your authorization code as well as the code where you create mService

Comment: @DalmTo Please check the update.

Comment: Can you confirm that your access token is indeed valid and hasn't expired? @JackD

Comment: When I am using the token on the Oauth 2.0 playground that will work. Till now what I found is that may be google not sending the OAuth token into the header when the app requesting the inserting events.

Comment: But are you refreshing this access token anywhere?

Comment: @ale13 nope. I am not refreshing the token anywhere in the application but it may be possible that google library may refresh the token. I am not sure about it.

Comment: Hi there @JackD! After reading all of this I have some doubts, are you using third party libraries or Google ones? If you are not refreshing the access token, please do so to prevent a stale token issue.